# MongoDB GridFS - How to use mongofiles(or some other utility) to delete all files?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to clean all the files from the GridFS of a particular Mongo database.  The mongofiles command line utility has a delete function but I don't know how to tell it do delete "all files".
I've been using MongoVue to select and delete the files in the fs view of GridFS but that only lets you delete specific number of selected files.

What I'm looking for is the SQL equivalent of
Delete * FROM

Answer (score 3):

```
    db.fs.files.remove({})
    db.fs.chunks.remove({})
    db.repairDatabase()  (cleans out the memory)
```

running these commands should remove all files

Comment: Dropping the collections is the right way to go. You can run repair or compact to reclaim disk space but be aware that it will heavily impact the performance of your database!

Comment: @wdberkeley Clearly your do not understand the GridFS spec. Indexes are created along with the default "files" and "chunks" collections. So dropping them will remove the indexes as well as removing the items. It seems more clear with each day that you should not be employed in you present role.

Comment: Actually, since there's no separate step to create the collections, the existence of the indexes is ensured with GridFS writes - subject to some caching to avoid a lot of extra no-op roundtrips to the server. Dropping the indexes means they'll just be recreated when the collections are recreated upon first insertion. Is that what you thought the problem would be, that the collections would lack the proper indexes?

Comment: @wdberkeley Dropping the collection doesn't clear GridFS.  I'm using MongoVUE to drop the collection and the GridFS store is still there and I can pull up the files.

Comment: @user3295173 I was able to run the first command (files.remove) but when I tried to run the second the connection dropped and the MongoDB service died. I was able to restart MongoDB but every time I try to run the chunks.remove MongoDB dies.  This is on Windows with MongoDB version 2.6.1
Do I need to change the command order? Chunks first, then files?

Comment: @user3295173 Confirmed, if you do chunks first then files MongoDB is happy, please fix your answer and I'll mark it as the answer